# Is it safe to delete an EFI partition that is likely a residual one left behind by Ubuntu

Tags: hard-disk, uefi

I have two disks on my computer: an SSD on which my windows is installed and a HDD which had my ubuntu. I recently deleted Ubuntu and now have the space left as unallocated space on my disk. I am unable to reallocate it owing to the presence of this EFI partition:
[image]
I want to find out whether this partition is safe to be deleted. I believe it is some kind of remnant of my improperly removed Ubuntu installation. Can someone please let me know how I can be sure and how I can proceed safely to reclaim the unallocated volume?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to find out the GPT partition UUID of the "problem" partition, and then verify that that UUID is not present in any UEFI boot entry you want to use.

I would recommend booting the system in UEFI mode using a Linux live media, and running `lsblk -o +partuuid` to view the partition UUIDs of each partition. Then `sudo efibootmgr -v` to view the UEFI boot variables, including the partition UUIDs they refer to. If the UUID of the problem partition is not present in the `efibootmgr -v` output or the boot variable clearly refers to the already-removed Ubuntu, you can remove the partition... and you may want to use `efibootmgr` to remove the boot variable too.

If you want to find out how to do that *using Windows tools*, that is off topic here in Unix & Linux StackExchange; please ask again in [SuperUser StackExchange](https://superuser.com) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This sounds like something I could try, although I am not fully familiar with the methods and terms you have used. Could you please point me to a resource that might help me follow your advice?

Answer (score 0):

You could mount the EFI system partition, and double-check that it only has an `EFI/Ubuntu` directory, and no `EFI/Microsoft` directory.

You could do this by booting a Ubuntu installer in "Try Ubuntu" mode, e.g. using the *Disks* app in Ubuntu.

Or, you could try using Windows.  For example, you might be able to mount the EFI partition to a Windows drive letter, using the *Disk Management* app you have screenshot in your question.  See [Change a drive letter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-drive-letter).

Finally, if you use `fdisk` on the Ubuntu command line, you could:

1. Write down the number, start sector, end sector, and type of the partition.
2. Delete the partition.
3. Reboot into Windows.
4. If Windows breaks, you can use `fdisk` to re-create the deleted partition.  All the partition data will still be there.  (Unless you created a new partition to overwrite it!)

Comment: This sounds like it might solve my problem, however, I am not super savvy with this stuff. I am a beginner to this stuff. Could you please point to a source with more detailed instructions or elaborate on your answer if it is not too much trouble?